# Cannot install nginx ingress with helm from nginx-stable when specifying namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a question. I am trying to install nginx with helm 3 but it is not working when i specify the namespace.
Any idea why ? it works without.

```
helm install nginx-release nginx-stable/nginx-ingres -n ingress-basic
Error: failed to download "nginx-stable/nginx-ingres" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

Answer (score 6):

Your command has a typo, you typed `nginx-stable/nginx-ingres` and it should be `nginx-stable/nginx-ingress`.

Following the [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/), your are using the right repository for the official NGINX Ingress. To successfully install it using helm you have to run the following commands:

1. Add NGINX Helm repository:

   ```
   $ helm repo add nginx-stable https://helm.nginx.com/stable
   $ helm repo update
   ```
2. To install the chart with the release name my-release (my-release is the name that you choose):

   ```
   $ helm install my-release nginx-stable/nginx-ingress
   ```

In your scenario the command should look like this:

```
$ helm install nginx-release nginx-stable/nginx-ingress -n ingress-basic
```

Before running the above command, you have to create the namespace:

```
kubectl create namespace ingress-basic
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use a wrong stable repo.
Use this

```
helm install ingress-basic stable/nginx-ingress -n ingress-basic
```

Comment: He is using a correct repository, he is trying to use the Oficial NGINX Ingress.

Comment: @mWatney Thanks Was not aware of the different repo